# Spacing after section title with res.cls

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, cv, resume

It is possible to change spacing after a section title with following

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1em}{2em}
```

However, when I am using `res.cls` by

```
\documentclass{res}
```

and try to set the spacing after section title, I am getting this error

```
Argument of \section has an extra } \ttl@extract\section
Paragraph ended before \section was complete  \ttl@extract\section
Paragraph ended before \in@ was complete  \ttl@extract\section
Too many }'s \ttl@extract\section

Missing number, treated as zero \section{Objective}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \section{Objective)
```

Is there a way to manually specify spacing after section title while using `res.cls`? I was only  able to change the spacing after a section (not the title) through `res.cls`.

Comment: What is `res.cls`? Is [this](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) it?

Comment: yes that is it, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [resume document class](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) from NYU uses its own definitions for `section` etc. These are quite different to the standard definitions, so packages such as `titlesec` are unlikely to work. A crude workaround is to tack some space onto the definition of the `\section` macro.

```
\documentclass{res}
\makeatletter
\def\section#1{\@@section{#1}\vskip 5cm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Some text.
\section{Another section}
More text.
\end{document}
```